# what is the proof for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{4} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone provide a proof for the solution of this series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{4} $

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework problem...

Comment: [Oh, to see the heavens....](http://www.celestron.com/media/catalog/product/cache/2/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/2/22051_80lcm_large_1.jpg)

Comment: @T.Bongers This has to be one of my favorite responses on this website to date.

Comment: In case you did not get T.Bongers' quip, see [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of an older question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560816/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-frac1nn1n2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}} = {1 \over 4}:\
     {\large ?}}$
\begin{align}
{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}}=
{1/2 \over n} + {-1 \over n + 1} + {1/2 \over n + 2}
=\half\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over n + 1}} -
\half\pars{{1 \over n + 1} - {1 \over n + 2}}
\end{align}
Now, you have 'telescoping' series:
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + 1}\pars{n + 2}}}
=\half\sum_{n = \color{#f00}{\large 1}}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over n + 1}}
-\half\sum_{n = \color{#f00}{\large 2}}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n} - {1 \over n + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\half\pars{{1 \over 1} - {1 \over 1 + 1}}
=\color{#00f}{\large{1 \over 4}}
\end{align}

Comment: wow thanks man!

Comment: @JamesFair You're welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$$
so
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}&=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{1\times 2}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}
\end{align*}