# Find the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the sum of the following series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+2)}$$

I've already figured it out that it converges and, as it looks like a telescoping series, I also tried decomposing it into partial fractions, which would be
 $$\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+4}$$
But that doesn't seem to be helping me at all... Any ideas?

Comment: See also: [Find the sum of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560816/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-frac1nn1n2) and
[What is the proof for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{4}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721749/what-is-the-proof-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac1nn1n2-frac14)