# Use comparison test to show that $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$ converges and find its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Use comparison test to show that $\sum^{+\infty}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$ converges and find its limit

I tried expanding out the denominator, and then using the comparison test with $\frac{1}{k^3}$ but I think this is an incorrect use of the comparison test as I get divergence. I know that the limit is $\frac{1}{4}$ but I am not sure how to use the comparison test to then apply the limit.

Comment: To find the limit, see my answer on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000297/calculate-sum-n-1-infty-frac12n-frac1n1-frac12n4/1000306#1000306

Comment: The series is smaller than $\sum 1/k^3$ so converge.

Comment: use partial fraction decomposition, and it will telescope. otherwise integrate 2 times the Taylor series of $-\log(1-z)$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} & <\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+0)(k+0)}\\ & =\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k^3}\end{align}$$

It converges.

[Franko's telescoping sum:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000306/272831)

$$\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\left(\frac{1/2}{k(k+1)}-\frac{1/2}{(k+1)(k+2)}\right)$$

$$=\frac14$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}<\frac1{k^3}$$

Then

$$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}<\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{k^3}$$

I dont know an easy way to calculate it limit. But if you know something about [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) we can rewrite your summation as

$$\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}=\sum_{k\ge 0}k^{\underline {-3}}=\frac{k^{\underline {-2}}}{-2}\Bigg|^{\infty}_{0}=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: you are allowed to write it as a telescoping series..

Comment: @user1952009 yeah... Im allowed to be millonaire too but is not the case xD. I mean: this is the easier thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: It isn't, see simpleArt's answer (and think on this: is $\int_a^b f'(t) dt = f(b)-f(a)$ a telescoping sum afterall ?)

Answer (score 1):

Given that the *rising and falling factorials* are defined  as
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 n^{\,\overline {\,m\,} }  = n\left( {n + 1} \right)\, \cdots \;\left( {n + m - 1} \right) \\ 
 n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  = n\left( {n - 1} \right)\, \cdots \;\left( {n - \left( {m + 1} \right)} \right) \\ 
 n^{\,\underline {\, - \,m\,} }  = \frac{1}{{\left( {n + m} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } }} = \frac{1}{{\left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\overline {\,m\,} } }} \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
where here we consider $n$ and $m$ integers,
and that it is not difficult to demonstrate that
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \Delta _{\,n} \,n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  = \left( {n + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  - n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }  = m\,n^{\,\underline {\,m - 1\,} }  \hfill \\
  \sum\limits_{k = a}^{b - 1} {k^{\,\underline {\,m\,} } } \quad \left| {\;a < b} \right.\quad  = \frac{1}
{{m + 1}}\left( {b^{\,\underline {\,m + 1\,} }  - a^{\,\underline {\,m + 1\,} } } \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
Then
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{k\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}
{{\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {k + 2} \right)\left( {k + 3} \right)}}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty  {k^{\,\underline {\, - 3\,} } }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {k^{\,\underline {\, - 3\,} } }  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( { - \frac{1}
{2}\left( {n^{\,\underline {\, - 2\,} }  - 0^{\,\underline {\, - 2\,} } } \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( { - \frac{1}
{2}\left( {\frac{1}
{{\left( {n + 1} \right)\left( {n + 2} \right)}} - \frac{1}
{{1 \cdot 2}}} \right)} \right) = \frac{1}
{4} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Answer (score -3):

Yes you compare with $\frac{1}{k^3}$, as follows, 
$$\frac{k^3}{k(k+1)(k+2)}\rightarrow 1$$ so the series converges, because $\sum \frac{1}{k^3}$ converges.