# Find the summation of the series: $\sum_{n=1}^{5}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> Find the summation of the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{5}\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)(2n+3)}$$

I want hints to solve this problem.

It is a finite sum, but it is an entrance based question and hardly they allow calculators.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: You looking for general or just manually go through 1 to 5?

Comment: Partial fractions could help, I bet.

Comment: @riicheyv  It's a finite series, there are only 5 terms, so you can put it in the calculator? It's not very elegant, I admit, otherwise Claude's hint would be a suggestion.

Comment: It's an entrance based question and hardly they allow calculators. @imranfat.

Comment: Somewhat similar question: [Find the sum of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560816/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-frac1nn1n2)

Comment: @riicheyvgouchami  Ah, that makes a big difference...

Comment: I am voting to leave open since there is an explicit request for hints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute
$$
\frac1{(2n-1)(2n+1)}-\frac1{(2n+1)(2n+3)}
$$
and think [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Comment: Oh... I didn't see it was a finite series. I will leave this answer in case someone is interested in the infinite series, or a sum to a variable upper limit.