# $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of the series $\sum_1^\infty{\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}}$?

I expanded it via partial fractions but it does not look like a telescoping series which I was expecting.

Am I missing something obvious or easy manipulation here?

Comment: $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$$

Comment: `... telescoping series` $\;\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n (n+1)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right)$

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560816/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-frac1nn1n2/560897#560897

Comment: take limit to finite representation of the sum, which is $\tfrac{1}{4}-\tfrac{1}{2(n+1)(n+2)}$

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$\dfrac2{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac{n+2-n}{n(n+1)(n+2)}=\dfrac1{n(n+1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)}=f(n)-f(n+1)$$ where $f(m)=\dfrac1{m(m+1)}$