# Evaluate the following sum$ \frac {1}{1×4×7} +\frac {1}{4×7×10}+\frac {1}{7×10×13}+....\frac {1}{25×28×31}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Evaluate the following sum

$$\frac {1}{1×4×7} +\frac {1}{4×7×10}+\frac {1}{7×10×13}+....\frac {1}{25×28×31}$$

How could i solve this problem?

Thanks very much for help

Comment: Does it telescope?

Comment: What does  "telescope" mean?

Comment: A sum $\sum a_n$ telescopes if there is a convenient sequence $b_n$ with $a_n=b_n-b_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Related since the techniques in the following link may also be applied here: [Find the sum of the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560816)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial fractions gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{n(n+3)(n+6) } =\frac{1}{18} \left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{2}{n+3}+\frac{1}{n+6} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
so the sum does telescope
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{18} \left[ \left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{2}{4}+\frac{1}{7} \right)+ \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{7}+\frac{1}{10} \right)+\cdots+\left(\frac{1}{22}-\frac{2}{25}+\frac{1}{28} \right)+\left(\frac{1}{25}-\frac{2}{28}+\frac{1}{31} \right)\right] \\
\frac{1}{18} \left( \frac{1}{1}- \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{28}+\frac{1}{31}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{9}{217}}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

*Hint.*
Try to decompose each fraction like this:
$$\frac{1}{(n-3) \cdot n \cdot (n+3)} = \frac{1}{18} \left( \frac{1}{n-3} - \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n+3} \right) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:
$$\frac { 1 }{ a\left( a+3 \right) \left( a+6 \right)  } =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ a\left( a+3 \right)  } -\frac { 1 }{ \left( a+3 \right) \left( a+6 \right)  }  \right] =\frac { 1 }{ 6 } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ a } -\frac { 1 }{ a+3 }  \right) -\frac { 1 }{ 3 } \left( \frac { 1 }{ a+3 } -\frac { 1 }{ a+6 }  \right)  \right] =\\ =\frac { 1 }{ 18 } \left[ \frac { 1 }{ a } -\frac { 2 }{ a+3 } +\frac { 1 }{ a+6 }  \right] $$

Answer (score 0):

One does the trick like the following:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{2}{n+3}+\dfrac{1}{n+6}\right)&=\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)+\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+2}\right)\\
&~~~~+\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+2}-\dfrac{1}{n+3}\right)+\sum_{n}\left(-\dfrac{1}{n+3}+\dfrac{1}{n+4}\right)\\
&~~~~+\sum_{n}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+5}-\dfrac{1}{n+4}\right)+\sum_{n}\left(-\dfrac{1}{n+5}+\dfrac{1}{n+6}\right)
\end{align*}
and finally telescoping takes place.