# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2000} \frac {1}{n^3+3n^2+2n}\lt \frac {1}{4}$

Tags: inequality, summation

Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{2000} \frac {1}{n^3+3n^2+2n}\lt \frac {1}{4}.$$

I don't know a way to prove this, just instantly saw that:

$$n^3+3n^2+2n = n(n+1)(n+2).$$

But think this isn't useful at all.

Any hints?

Comment: $ \frac {1}{n^3+3n^2+2n} = \frac{1}{2x} - \frac{1}{x+1} +\frac{1}{2(x+2)}$, it's telescroping

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560816/find-the-sum-of-the-series-sum-frac1nn1n2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact

$ \displaystyle \frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}  = \dfrac 12 \dfrac{(n+2)-n}{n(n+1)(n+2)} = \dfrac12 \left( \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} - \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \right)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The factorization you cite should suggest a partial fraction decomposition leading to a telescoping series. This would prove that the sum all the way to infinity is exactly $\frac 14$. Since your sum deletes some terms, it is less.

Answer (score 0):

Partial fractions:
\begin{align*}
\frac1{n^3+3n^2+2n}&=\frac1{n(n+1)(n+2)}\\
&=\frac{\frac12}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{\frac12}{n+2}
\end{align*}

Then we can prove (by induction)
$$\sum_{n=1}^M\frac1{n^3+3n^2+2n}=\frac12-\frac14-\frac1{2(M+1)}+\frac1{2(M+2)}=\frac14-\frac1{2(M+1)(M+2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

one should have the following :

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\frac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}&=\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\bigg(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\bigg)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}-\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\bigg)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{2000}\bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}\bigg)\\
&=\bigg(1-\frac{1}{2001}\bigg)-\frac{1}{2}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2001}-\frac{1}{2002}\bigg)\\
&=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2001}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2001}+\frac{1}{4004}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4002}+\frac{1}{4004}\\
&<\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4002}+\frac{1}{4002}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}